# What materials can bend or reflect gamma rays?

Tags: material-science, reflection, lenses, gamma-rays

I have heard that gold can be used as a lens for gamma rays, but what exactly could reflect them? Having this technology could make something like a Dyson sphere much more efficient, I believe.